# Como alinhar verticalmente icones do font awesome?

Tags: html, css

Gostaria que o ícone do Font Awesome ficasse alinhando verticalmente no centro da div `<nav>`, igual ao item da classe `logo` em uma tela menor que 480px. Tentei com `line-height`, mas não funcionou como o outro.

[image: Exemplo]

Código:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

:root {
    --texto-branco: #f2f2f2;
    --fundo-preto:#262626;
    --fundo-azul:#009DFF;
}


nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    padding: 0 10%;
    background: var(--fundo-preto);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    line-height: 64px;
    color: var(--texto-branco);
}

.menu {
    color: var(--texto-branco);
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    display: none;
}

ul {
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 16px;
    list-style: none;
}

li:hover {
    background: var(--fundo-azul);
}

a {
    color: var(--texto-branco);
    line-height: 64px;
    text-decoration: none;
}



@media  (max-width: 480px) {
    .menu {
        display: block;
    }

    ul {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a3703589d3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <title>VM Design</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <nav>
          <div class="logo"><p>M</p></div>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Projetos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Fale Comigo</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
      </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta usar Flexbox, aplicando os seguintes estilos dentro da *media query*:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

A *mágica* é feita pelo `display: flex` e pelo `align-items`, que alinha os itens verticalmente por padrão. Como definimos essa propriedade como `center`, os itens serão alinhados ao centro.

Veja o exemplo final. Já está sem o `line-height`:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

:root {
    --texto-branco: #f2f2f2;
    --fundo-preto:#262626;
    --fundo-azul:#009DFF;
}


nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    padding: 0 10%;
    background: var(--fundo-preto);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    line-height: 64px;
    color: var(--texto-branco);
}

.menu {
    color: var(--texto-branco);
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    display: none;
}

ul {
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 16px;
    list-style: none;
}

li:hover {
    background: var(--fundo-azul);
}

a {
    color: var(--texto-branco);
    line-height: 64px;
    text-decoration: none;
}



@media  (max-width: 780px) {
    .menu {
        display: block;
    }

    ul {
        display: none;
    }

    nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a3703589d3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <title>VM Design</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <nav>
          <div class="logo"><p>M</p></div>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Projetos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Fale Comigo</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
      </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

<sup>Copiando a ideia da resposta do @Sam, alterei o *breakpoint* para ficar mais simples de visualizar as mudanças.</sup>

Para saber mais, leia [conceitos básicos do *flexbox*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceitos_Basicos_do_Flexbox), ou o [guia completo do flexbox no CSS Tricks<sup>(En)</sup>](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Tem como alinhar sem usar flex-box, porque quando eu for fazer o menu aberto para mobile o align-items não me causaria problemas?

Comment: Por que iria causar? Penso que não.

Comment: Quando eu mudar ul { display: none } para { display:block} ele ira alinhar esses itens veticalmente também, quando eles precisam ser algo como flex-start

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox na `nav` com a propriedade `align-items: center` que os elementos filhos ficarão alinhados verticalmente no centro. Agora, é preciso retirar o `float: right` que não vai funcionar no flexbox. No lugar você pode usar `margin-left: auto` que ícone irá se posicionar à  direita do contêiner (retire também o `float: left;` da logo que não vai ser mais necessário).

*No exemplo abaixo aumentei o breakpoint `max-width: 480px` para `780px` apenas para fim de visualização.*

**Exemplo:**

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

:root {
    --texto-branco: #f2f2f2;
    --fundo-preto:#262626;
    --fundo-azul:#009DFF;
}


nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    padding: 0 10%;
    background: var(--fundo-preto);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex; /* adicionado */
    align-items: center; /* adicionado */
}

.logo {
    /*float: left; removido */
    line-height: 64px;
    color: var(--texto-branco);
}

.menu {
    color: var(--texto-branco);
    cursor: pointer;
    /*float: right; removido */
    display: none;
    margin-left: auto; /* adicionado */
}

ul {
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 16px;
    list-style: none;
}

li:hover {
    background: var(--fundo-azul);
}

a {
    color: var(--texto-branco);
    line-height: 64px;
    text-decoration: none;
}



@media  (max-width: 780px) {
    .menu {
        display: block;
    }

    ul {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav>
    <div class="logo"><p>M</p></div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projetos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fale Comigo</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Vou seguir a sua sugestão e aumentar o _breakpoint_ para ficar mais fácil de visualizar as mudanças. Boa ideia. :)

Comment:  só o oro!...

Comment: Tem como eu fazer isso sem usar flexbox? Porque isso me causa problemas quando eu for mudar o display ul para block quando eu for fazer a parte do menu aberta.

Comment: Tem sim. Coloque na classe .menu: `position: relative; top: 50%; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%);`